# capture group with optional second capture group containing first group pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

So i am trying to apply regex to a string in javascript. I just can't get the right pattern.

I Basically have a multiline string that contains a name with an optional amount at the end. Something like this `Warrior II x2`. I want one capture group for the name and one for the amount without x. So this should capture `{Warrior II,2}`

I tried this: `^(.+)(?:x(\d+))?$`. the problem is this;
the `.+` will always match everything, including the amount. to the second capture group will always be empty. And since the name can contain anything even numbers and non ascii stuff I can't really replace `.+` with something like `\D+`

So the question is how do I force regex to always capture the second group if it exists and not include that part in the first group. I even tried the lazy modifier with the `.+` but that did no work either.

I hope i described my problem understandably.

I tested most of my regex with regex101.com

Comment: By _multi-lined_, do you mean each line contains just this item ? Is that why you are using the anchors ?

Comment: yeah, each line contains only one name plus the optional amount

Comment: Looks like this `^(.+?)[ \t]*(?:x(\d+))?$` https://regex101.com/r/UJDhH6/1

Comment: well looks like that worked. seems like i applied the lazy modifier wrong. i applied it to the whole first group, not inside the group thank you for your help

Comment: No problem.. test it on all you expect to see.